# How to access a function inside a function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I suppose the title is somewhat misleading but I didn't know how else to put it.

I have a function that lets a little pop-up window appear when a link is clicked (a confirmation message whether or not to delete an article).

I have also got a function that  posts data to a *php* file and inserts the data that I get (also a list of articles) back into a div element.

When I try to use the function for the delete confirmation on a list of articles I originally generated with PHP, everything works, however when I try clicking on a (essentially the same) link inside the list of articles I inserted into the div with *jquery*, the function does not seem to work (i.e. the confirmation message does not appear).

I assume it's because the link is inserted after the js file loads but is there some way to make this function global so that it also works on the stuff I insert later?

```
$('.delete').click(function () {
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#dialog')
        .attr('title', 'Do you want to delete this article?')
        .text('If you click Delete, the entire article and all comments attached to it will be erased.')
        .dialog({
            buttons: {
                'Delete': function() { window.location.href = link; },
                'Cancel': function() { $(this).dialog('close'); }
            },
            closeOnEscape: true,
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            show: 'drop',
            hide: 'drop',
            modal: true
        });
});
```

Comment: Can you show some sample code?

Comment: you have a few options: 1. use onclick, 2. after you insert the HTML into the page - you'll have to bind the button to the JS function. 3. generate the DOM elements and append them. you can bind before or after you append

Comment: Don't post code in comment, edit your question instead...

Comment: np, see @Morgan Wilde 's answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to listen for the event by using the `.on()` method of jQuery (the manual - [jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/on/)).

The reason being - once you start adding new elements **dynamically** that need to respond to events, you need to have a way of informing your event listeners to react to them. And `.on()` does just that.

A quick example would be:

```
$("div.parent_of_button").on("click", ".class-of-button", function(event){
    $(this).text('clicked!');
});
```

What this means is that all elements of class `.class-of-button` that you will add after page load, will respond to clicks.

**edit**

Sometimes it helps if `.on()` is attached to the parent of all your dynamically created elements, and then the element you're targeting is the second attribute of the `.on()` method, as in the example.

Comment: OK I changed my code to    ``$('.delete').on("click", function (event) {
 var link = $(this).attr('href');
 $('#dialog').attr('title', 'Do you want to delete this article?').text('If you click Delete, the entire article and all comments attached to it will be erased.').dialog({ buttons: {
  'Delete': function() {
  window.location.href = link;
 }, 'Cancel': function() {
  $(this).dialog('close');
 }}, closeOnEscape: true, draggable: false, resizable: false, show: 'drop', hide: 'drop', modal: true});
});
`` but it still only works for content generated server-side

Comment: Still does not work. Do you mean the direct parent? every one of my delete links is in a respective div called menu. Should I target that or one div in which all my delete links are?

Comment: @user2209024 as long as it is higher up than the button in the DOM chain, it should work. Try `console.log('hello')`ing inside `.on()` and see if you don't get anything on dynamically added elements.

Comment: OK when I use a div in which all the links are, it works just fine ;) Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the JQuery live feature before attaching events to your links : http://api.jquery.com/live/

You could aslo listen click event on a common ancester of the elements and look if the targetted element is the link you expect :

```
commonAncestor.click(function(e){
if('A'==e.target.nodeName)
    // do what you want to
});
```

Comment: live is deprecated, .on() is the way to go now

Comment: thanks, didn't use jquery for a while. Anyway, listening for events on the common ancestor is way far faster.

Comment: Actually they can be slower: _Attaching many delegated event handlers near the top of the document tree can degrade performance. Each time the event occurs, jQuery must compare all selectors of all attached events of that type to every element in the path from the event target up to the top of the document. For best performance, attach delegated events at a document location as close as possible to the target elements._